# calculate line integral directly and via stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I've calculated line integral $\int_cydx+zdy+xdx,$
where $c$ is intersection of $(x^2+y^2)^2=y^2-x^2\ (y\geq 0)$ and $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ positively oriented when looking from the point $(0,1,0)$, directly and via Stokes formula. But i get two different solutions, $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac{1}{2}$. Is either one of them correct?

Comment: Considering that both solutions differ by a sign I assume you have misinterpreted "positively oriented" in one of the integrals.

Comment: Very likely but i am busting my head to find out in which one.

Comment: please provide what u tried or where you stuck.